QGIS - unable to access PostGIS layers on remote server due to name change
I'm running QGIS 3.40 on Windows 10, connecting to a remote PostGIS server. About 4 years ago I worked on a project where I ended up doing all of the querying of data on the server, creating tables and materialized views which I then brought into the QGIS project to symbolise and create maps.
I've been asked to revisit the work, but have run into an issue. In the intervening period, the IT dept retired the box where the database was hosted, and migrated all the data to a new server. The name has changed from 'server 1' to 'server 2'.
When I try and open the QGIS project, it thinks for a while, then prompts me for my credentials. These are now not pointing at the correct resource. I can select 'ignore for session' and cancel, but it seems to want this for every layer. And there are dozens of them, so totally impractical to cancel through them all and then use something like the change Datasource plugin to fix the paths after the fact.
A couple of us tried to edit the .qgs file manually to change the server name, but this hasn't made any difference, including creating a new QGIS profile for that server. Still getting prompted each time.
Is this irretrievably broken, or is there something else anyone can suggest? To be clear, the problem starts immediately on opening the QGIS project, so none of the layers will load.

Do you have a PostGIS connection setting for your 'server 1' in the Data Source Manager ?

I deleted the connection in the browser because it was pointing at a non-existent location. I have set one up to server 2 now
